# can't read int value from sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have tried this code in C#, and it's not working - I can't get an input id, every time I run it, the value of id is 0.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=boy;Password=coco");        

int id;

con.Open();
string sql = "select * from Staff_Management where Emp_Name = '"+sName+"'; ";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (read.Read())
{
    id = read.GetInt32(0);
    TM_AC_SelectId.Text = id.ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error 009 ");
}

con.Close();
```

Comment: `its not working` We get that a lot - too often in fact. [Debug your code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) and fix the part that is not working

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Are you ***200%*** sure that the *first column* from your `SELECT *` is really your `id` ?? If you really only need the `Id` - then why use `SELECT *` at all - use `SELECT id FROM ....`  and then you can use the `.ExecuteScalar()` function to get the one value you're interested in !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to follow the accepted best practices for ADO.NET programming:

- use **parameters** for your query - ***always*** - no exceptions
- use the `using(...) { .... }` construct to ensure proper and quick disposal of your resources
- select really **only** those columns that you need - don't just use `SELECT *` out of lazyness - **specify** your columns that you really need!

Change your code to this:

```
// define connection string (typically loaded from config) and query as strings
string connString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=boy;Password=coco";
string query = "SELECT id FROM dbo.Staff_Management WHERE Emp_Name = @EmpName;";

// define SQL connection and command in "using" blocks
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))       
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    // set the parameter value
    cmd.Parameter.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = sName;

    // open connection, execute scalar, close connection
    con.Open();
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    int id;

    if(result != null)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(result.ToString(), out id)
        {
            // do whatever when the "id" is properly found  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP, one of the reasons to specify the columns explicitly is also to help keep the nexus of any exception rooted in the source.  For example, with your approach, if you assume the first column is an int, but it's a string, then the exception or error bubbles up from the reader, when in fact the problem was in the query.  If you were explicit, then the error would likely tell you "Your query's bad" rather than "your use of the resultset is bad."  Which is more informative?

Comment: Lastly, OP's question assumes that there will only ever be one or zero results, which is a fragile assumption to make, especially when using names as a filter (John/Jennifer Smith?).  It would be better, probably, to stick with ExecuteCommand + reader, and deal with the multiple resultset in a more explicit manner (in a manner which gives you control, rather than leaving it to chance).